# Getting the video path of capture video using default camera in android

Tags: android

I am declaring a global variable for String selectedImagePath. On button click I am  calling video capture code

```
Intent intent=new Intent("android.media.action.VIDEO_CAPTURE");
intent.putExtra("android.intent.extra.durationLimit", 120);  
startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_VIDEO_CAPTURED);
```

OnActivity result I am getting video path 
           `selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri);`

onActivityResult Code 
  I am getting the value here properly

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub

 if(resultCode==RESULT_OK)
 {
  if(requestCode==REQUEST_VIDEO_CAPTURED)
  {
      Toast.makeText(VideoPostActivity.this, "Video Recorded", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();   

       selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri);

       System.out.println("selected image path"+selectedImagePath);

      /* imgPublishVideo.setEnabled(true);
          imgRecordVideo.setEnabled(false);*/





  }


 }
  if(resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED)
 {
 Toast.makeText(VideoPostActivity.this,  "Cancelled!",  Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

 }


 }
```

I am not getting value here

```
SetMyVideoPostAsyncTask myVideoPostAsyncTask=new SetMyVideoPostAsyncTask(VideoPostActivity.this,videoTitle,videoComment,selectedImagePath);
myVideoPostAsyncTask.execute();

public String getPath(Uri uri)
{       
        String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };        
        Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);        
        if(cursor!=null)         
        {            

            int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);          
            cursor.moveToFirst();          
            return cursor.getString(column_index);       
            }       
        else 
            return null;    
}
```

but I am not able to pass selectedImagePath value from activity it is going null can anybody tell what is problem? What do I do?

Comment: Can you post OnActivityResult Code?

Comment: Change your intent values/extras to be constants rather than hard coded strings. This way if android changes them you won't have to fix your code: 
Intent intent=new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_DURATION_LIMIT, 120);  
startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_VIDEO_CAPTURED);

Comment: additionally, instead of wasting a call to getColumnIndexOrThrow, you can simply do cursor.getString(0); and remove your int column_index = ...; since there will never be any other rows

Comment: Can you post more code for SetMyVideoPostAsyncTask ? Is that a class within the class that holds "onActivityResult" or is this its own separate class? If its separate you will have to pass it your selectedPath string.

Comment: @dymmeh its a separate class i have pass the value

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4237/discussion-between-mohan-and-dymmeh)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
private String videoPath = "";

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(resultCode==RESULT_OK)
    {

      Uri vid = data.getData();
      videoPath = getRealPathFromURI(vid);
    }


}

public String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentUri) {
    String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
    Cursor cursor = managedQuery(contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
    int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    return cursor.getString(column_index);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> managedQuery is deprecated and I am testing on `Marshmallow 6.0`

So you can use `FilePath` class which is tested on `Marshmallow 6.0` and previous lower version also. You have to  call it by `FilePath.getPath(your_context, uri);`

```
    import android.content.ContentUris;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.database.Cursor;
    import android.net.Uri;
    import android.os.Build;
    import android.os.Environment;
    import android.provider.DocumentsContract;
    import android.provider.MediaStore;

    public class FilePath {

        public static String getPath(final Context context, String string) {
            return getPath(context, Uri.parse(string));
        }

        public static String getPath(final Context context, final Uri uri) {

            final boolean isKitKat = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT;

            // DocumentProvider
            if (isKitKat && DocumentsContract.isDocumentUri(context, uri)) {
                // ExternalStorageProvider
                if (isExternalStorageDocument(uri)) {
                    final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                    final String[] split = docId.split(":");
                    final String type = split[0];

                    if ("primary".equalsIgnoreCase(type)) {
                        return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + split[1];
                    }

                    // TODO handle non-primary volumes
                }
                // DownloadsProvider
                else if (isDownloadsDocument(uri)) {

                    final String id = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                    final Uri contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(
                            Uri.parse("content://downloads/public_downloads"), Long.valueOf(id));

                    return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, null, null);
                }
                // MediaProvider
                else if (isMediaDocument(uri)) {
                    final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                    final String[] split = docId.split(":");
                    final String type = split[0];

                    Uri contentUri = null;
                    if ("image".equals(type)) {
                        contentUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                    } else if ("video".equals(type)) {
                        contentUri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                    } else if ("audio".equals(type)) {
                        contentUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                    }

                    final String selection = "_id=?";
                    final String[] selectionArgs = new String[] {
                            split[1]
                    };

                    return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, selection, selectionArgs);
                }
            }
            // MediaStore (and general)
            else if ("content".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
                return getDataColumn(context, uri, null, null);
            }
            // File
            else if ("file".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
                return uri.getPath();
            }

            return null;
        }

        /**
         * Get the value of the data column for this Uri. This is useful for
         * MediaStore Uris, and other file-based ContentProviders.
         *
         * @param context The context.
         * @param uri The Uri to query.
         * @param selection (Optional) Filter used in the query.
         * @param selectionArgs (Optional) Selection arguments used in the query.
         * @return The value of the _data column, which is typically a file path.
         */
        public static String getDataColumn(Context context, Uri uri, String selection,
                String[] selectionArgs) {

            Cursor cursor = null;
            final String column = "_data";
            final String[] projection = {
                    column
            };

            try {
                cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs,
                        null);
                if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                    final int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(column);
                    return cursor.getString(column_index);
                }
            } finally {
                if (cursor != null)
                    cursor.close();
            }
            return null;
        }


        /**
         * @param uri The Uri to check.
         * @return Whether the Uri authority is ExternalStorageProvider.
         */
        public static boolean isExternalStorageDocument(Uri uri) {
            return "com.android.externalstorage.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
        }

        /**
         * @param uri The Uri to check.
         * @return Whether the Uri authority is DownloadsProvider.
         */
        public static boolean isDownloadsDocument(Uri uri) {
            return "com.android.providers.downloads.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
        }

        /**
         * @param uri The Uri to check.
         * @return Whether the Uri authority is MediaProvider.
         */
        public static boolean isMediaDocument(Uri uri) {
            return "com.android.providers.media.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
        }
    }
```