# How to get recorded video path in android ?

Tags: android, video, nullpointerexception, media

I am trying to capture a video using intent and then storing it inside my SD-card, Now what I want is to get the path of that recorded video, so for that I wrote following code.

For recording video I have following code.

```
record.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                File storageDir = new File(Environment
                        .getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/filetoupload/");
                if (!storageDir.exists()) {
                    storageDir.mkdirs();
                }

                try {
                    imageToStore = new File(storageDir, "" + "video.mp4");
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
                    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                            Uri.fromFile(imageToStore));
                    startActivityForResult(intent, CAPTURE_VIDEO);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
```

And for getting it's path I have written following code.

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            switch (requestCode) {
            case CAPTURE_VIDEO:

                Uri videoUri = data.getData();
                String videopath = getRealPathFromURI(videoUri);
                System.out.println("Path is" + videopath);
                mEditPath = new EditText(this);
                mEditPath.setText(videopath);
                mEditPath.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                new videopath().execute();

                Intent intent = new Intent(RecordVideo.this,
                        SaveAudioVideo.class);
                startActivity(intent);

                break;

            default:
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

**Method**

```
public String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentUri) {
        String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        Cursor cursor = managedQuery(contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
        int column_index = cursor
                .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        return cursor.getString(column_index);
    }
```

I have also tried by passing `MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA` as `MediaStore.Videos.Media.DATA` also but this is also not working. Whenever I press Ok button after recording video always I am getting following `NullPointerException` error.

```
02-25 13:10:19.214: E/AndroidRuntime(9075): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-25 13:10:19.214: E/AndroidRuntime(9075): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1001, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=file:///mnt/sdcard/filetoupload/video.mp4 }} to activity {iqual.fidol_final/iqual.fidol_final.RecordVideo}: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-25 13:10:19.214: E/AndroidRuntime(9075):     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3135)
02-25 13:10:19.214: E/AndroidRuntime(9075):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3178)
02-25 13:10:19.214: E/AndroidRuntime(9075):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:134)
02-25 13:10:19.214: E/AndroidRuntime(9075):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1277)
02-25 13:10:19.214: E/AndroidRuntime(9075):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-25 13:10:19.214: E/AndroidRuntime(9075):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
02-25 13:10:19.214: E/AndroidRuntime(9075):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4624)
02-25 13:10:19.214: E/AndroidRuntime(9075):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-25 13:10:19.214: E/AndroidRuntime(9075):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-25 13:10:19.214: E/AndroidRuntime(9075):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:809)
02-25 13:10:19.214: E/AndroidRuntime(9075):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:576)
02-25 13:10:19.214: E/AndroidRuntime(9075):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-25 13:10:19.214: E/AndroidRuntime(9075): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-25 13:10:19.214: E/AndroidRuntime(9075):     at iqual.fidol_final.RecordVideo.getRealPathFromURI(RecordVideo.java:206)
02-25 13:10:19.214: E/AndroidRuntime(9075):     at iqual.fidol_final.RecordVideo.onActivityResult(RecordVideo.java:183)
02-25 13:10:19.214: E/AndroidRuntime(9075):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:4672)
02-25 13:10:19.214: E/AndroidRuntime(9075):     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3131)
02-25 13:10:19.214: E/AndroidRuntime(9075):     ... 11 more
```

where line number 206 is

```
int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
```

and line number 183 is

```
 String videopath = getRealPathFromURI(videoUri);
```

I know it's clearly indicating `NullPointerException`  but somehow I am not able to figured it out why ?

Comment: Post `getRealPathFromURI` method.

Comment: @Hariharan, edited please have a look.

Comment: Why you are fetching the path when you can simply use path as `Environment
                        .getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/filetoupload/" + "video.mp4"`

Comment: @Kedarnath, I am renaming that file in some activity and then doing some other operation also.

Comment: Ok, How many video files you are refering at a time ? I mean is it one video only or more than one video ?

Comment: Only one video at a time

Comment: Suggestion, create a Global variable and set its value with this video file's path and when you updated the path, update that variable's value as well. This way searching path for your video file will be reduced. You dont need to do lot code. Just only a global variable handling. :)

Comment: @InnocentKiller any success ?

Comment: @Kedarnath, Nope buddy.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48349/discussion-between-kedarnath-and-innocentkiller)

Comment: @Kedarnath, can we discuss later please, as right now i am busy in some other work.

Comment: @InnocentKiller, sure as you wish :)

Comment: [this][1] or [this][2] should work .... :/


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7756349/getting-the-video-path-of-capture-video-using-default-camera-in-android
  [2]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3401579/get-filename-and-path-from-uri-from-mediastore