# Get path from recorded video

Tags: android, kotlin, uri, filepath

currently i am developing a simple app to record video using kotlin, but i have difficulties when i want to get absolute path from video i recorded before. Here is my code which is written in kotlin

```
    private fun dispatchTakeVideoIntent() {
        val intent = Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE)
        startActivityForResult(intent, 1)
    }

    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            val videoUri: Uri? = data?.data
            val file = File(videoUri?.path)
        }
    }
```

I have convert `videoUri` to path using `videoUri?.path` but it always return me with something like `/external/video/media/55`, whereas my video file path is something like `/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/video.mp4`

Could i get the file path instead of uri of my recorded video ? any help or hints will be much appreciated.

PS : this might have been asked before in another question : [How to get recorded video path in android ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22007679/how-to-get-recorded-video-path-in-android) but it didnt have any accepted answer so i think it is fine to asking again.

Comment: Please start telling the value of that uri. It should be something like `content://...../external/video/media/55` And indeed the path part is not a file system path. After that tell why you want a file system path as you can use the uri directly to do something with the video.

Comment: @blackapps my uri for that case is ```content://media/external/video/media/55```. i need file system path because i want to process it using FFmpeg later.

Comment: Then you should do a query() using a contentresolver for the .DATA column. But that column will very probably not be available on Android 10 up. The column .DISPLAY_NAME would give you the name of the file though. You could also query for column .RELATIVE.PATH on Android Q+ devices.

Comment: @blackapps if you could elaborate it in answer it would be very helpful

Comment: How to query() ? All is in the link you provided. Well.. nearly all.

Comment: Further you use ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE without providing a file path. If you did you would know that path already. It is done in the link you provided so i wonder why you did not already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Could i get the file path instead of uri of my recorded video ?

There is no requirement for the video to be recorded as a file on the filesystem, let alone in a location that you can access via the filesystem APIs.

If the scheme of the returned `Uri` happens to be `file`, then `getPath()` will return you a filesystem path to the file. However, there is no guarantee that you can use that file, and the `file` scheme has largely been banned since Android 7.0.

It is far more likely that the scheme will be `content`. That `Uri` could point to:

- A local file on external storage that your app could read
- A local file on external storage, but in a place that your app will lack read access to
- A local file on internal storage for the other app
- A local file on removable storage
- A local file that is encrypted and needs to be decrypted on the fly
- A stream of bytes held in a BLOB column in a database
- A piece of content that needs to be downloaded by the other app first
- ...and so on

And, just as with an `https` URL, there is no magic way to convert the path portion of the `Uri` to some filesystem path.

> i need file system path because i want to process it using FFmpeg later

I would start by seeing if anyone has an FFmpeg wrapper that can work with a `Uri`.

If that is unavailable, then you will need to make a copy of the content in a file that you control:

- Use `ContentResolver` and `openInputStream()` to get an `InputStream` on the content, passing in your `Uri`
- Open a `FileOutputStream` on some file (e.g., in `getCacheDir()`)
- Copy the bytes from the `InputStream` to the `FileOutputStream` (Kotlin has some great extension functions for this)

Or, rather than use `ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE`, use a camera library and take the video directly within your app, rather than trying to rely on a third-party app to take the video.

Comment: thank you for this great insight. Now i can achieve what i want by saving video first using `contentResolver` to my apps system folder (since external path in android is became more tricky to access)